# Looking for an approach to proving Inequivalence of norms

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, separable-spaces

X is a infinite dimensional,separable, Banach space with a Hamel Basis $\{e_a\}$. Let $\vert\!\vert x\vert\!\vert=\sum\vert x_a\vert$ ,
where $x=\sum(x_a e_a)$.
Prove that $\vert\!\vert\cdot\vert\!\vert$ is not equivalent to the original norm on X.

I am very confused about where to approach this from. I've tried assuming they are equivalent and proving it wrong to no avail. The other way I have tried to do it is to prove that it will not be complete with the new norm, but i cannot seem to do it that way either. Im not looking for an answer, just a nudge in the right direction.

Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $||x||_1 =\sum |x_a |$ and $||\cdot ||$ are equivalent. Then $(X, ||\cdot ||_1)$  is a Banach space. But the sequence $$z_n =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2 } e_{a_k}$$ is an Cauchy sequence in $(X, ||\cdot ||_1)$ without a limit. That gives a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, 
I did consider proofs of a similar nature, but since I am not too sure in my abilities, I was put off by the separability that we don't get to use with this approach. Unless I am worng? Do we need it here?

Comment: We don't need a separability here.